# What exactly last line of code is doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@user = find_user
@user_sport = UserSport.new(params[:iuser_sport])
@user.user_sports << @user_sport
```

What exactly last line of code is doing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is appending `@user_sport` to the `user_sports` array.

More info: [<<](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000225)

> Append—Pushes the given object on to
>   the end of this array. This expression
>   returns the array itself, so several
>   appends may be chained together.

[push](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000226) is also an equivalent method if you prefer to see the word. `<<` is common though, so it comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

From [rails API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

> Adds one or more objects to the
>   collection by creating associations in
>   the join table (collection.push and
>   collection.concat are aliases to this
>   method).

the '<<' creates association between activeRecords object,

here User has many UserSports so @user.user_sports << @user_sport defines association between @user and @user_sport.